# Android: Application Not Receiving Boot Complete

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm working on a relatively simple application, where it logs a message when a intent is called. However, the application never received *any* intents, explicit (`<package>.ACTION_SILENT_START` or implicit `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`)

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.<snip>.ade.kaiga">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon_circle"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- OnBoot Receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_PREPLACED" />
                <action android:name="com.<snip>.ade.kaiga.ACTION_SILENT_START" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 
    </application>
</manifest>
```

`com.<snip>.ade.kaiga.BootReceiver`:

```
package com.<snip>.ade.kaiga;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "KaigaBootReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "BOOOTTOTOTOTOTOTOTOT");
            BootService.enqueueWork(context, new Intent());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission in two places. You want it in the uses-permission element. But I don't think you want it in the permission attribute in the receiver:

```
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
```

By having that attribute there, you are saying that the *broadcaster* of the intent must hold the permission. That could really restrict when your receiver gets intents.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element#prmsn

Comment: After removing the permission, it still doesn't execute the log statement.

Comment: The only other thing I would suggest is removing the category from your intent filter. And if that doesn't work, remove the extra actions and get one working at a time. See which action causes things to break. I use BOOT_COMPLETED all the time and your code looks very typical. But I normally would not combine all those actions into 1 receiver.